# Boot from the same internal hard drive but enclosed in an external usb 3.0 case. Ubuntu 14.04.

Tags: 14.04, boot, usb, external-hdd

I have upgraded my ASUS U33jc with a ssd hd where I have installed 16.04. I placed my old (dual boot 14.04+W10) hd in an 3.0 usb external enclosure and I wanted to boot from it occasionally. From what I have found searching the web, that should be possible. Apparently booting from Windows is tricky but booting from Ubuntu should be OK. However, the hd gets recognized in the BIOS but I just get a black screen. It does not even get to the grub menu. Is this normal because of the dual boot Ubuntu+Windows? Am I doing something wrong?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Does the portable disk have a bootloader, (grub) on it?

If not, that may be the problem, you can add a menuentry to the internal drive's grub that will boot the USB drive.

If it does have a bootloader, boot-repair might be the answer.

Comment: Thank you @c-s-Cameron.  The portable disk now is no more than the former internal drive of the computer, which had a dual boot so it has grub. I believe that if I put it again inside the laptop, this will boot as it used to do. But let's assume I could use boot repair for the portable disk, I guess that what you are suggesting is that I boot with the present ssd drive (no grub as it only has ubuntu), then I would install boot-repair and will use it to repair the boot of the usb external disk. Can this be done without affecting the boot of the main ssd drive? thank you.

Comment: You can install boot-repair to the Ubuntu internal disk, (or to a flash drive). Use advanced options, make sure it is pointed at the correct drive before running. I have used it installed on a Ubuntu persistent flashdrive.

Comment: It does not work. I run boot-repair from a flash drive, reinstalled grub and placed it in sdb (the external drive) selecting ubuntu as the OS to boot by default. Everything seemed to work well but trying to boot from the external drive nothing happened, blank screen.

Comment: As a side note. Before that I tried it installing boot-repair to the internal disk but when selecting to place grub in sdb and selecting ubuntu (in sdb not in sda) a message appeared asking me to run boot-repair from a flas drive. I did not repair anything but after that grub appeared at boot with the 3 options, ubuntu from sda (internal disk) and ubuntu and windows from sdb (external disk) not even habin sdb pluged in. After pluging in sdb I wasn't able to boot from this menu either. I guess I can hide this menu in the future modifying grub settings.